# Deleting objects in callback function

Tags: c++, oop, pointers, memory-management, dangling-pointer

I am sending an HTTP request to save/update data on the server. The request is made asynchronously and a callback function is called when it completes. Everything works fine except that sometimes, the application crashes in the callback.

This is what I am doing:

```
user = new User();
user->saveOnServer();
user->zombie = true;  // Mark the user that it needs to be deleted in the callback.
```

In `User`, I have a `saveOnServer()` method:

```
void User::saveOnServer(){
    Request *request = new Request();

    // Send request to the server and register the callback.
    request ->setCallback(&userCallback, (void*)this);
}
```

The callback:

```
void userCallback(void *data){
    User *user = (User*)data;

    // Do something here.
    // Delete user if it's a zombie.
    if(user->zombie)
        delete user;
}
```

At times, I need to create a new user after sending a request to the server:

```
user = new User();
user->saveOnServer();
user->zombie = true;
// Some code comes here.
if(user)
    delete user;
user = new User();
```

The problem is that in such cases, the application crashes when deleting the user in the callback as it has already been deleted. Another issue is that the callback deletes user but `user` pointer in `main` is still pointing to some address (dangling pointer) and so I again try to delete it.

I am not sure what is the best way of managing memory in this case. I have `zombie` in place because there are cases when I do not want the callback to delete the user.

Comment: Why would you want a server to delete an object allocated by a client I'm wondering?

Comment: Server deletes nothing. Client has a callback to delete object after request ends.

Comment: The callback is not called by the server when processing the request completes then? Very interesting ... I'm just going to jump to the point. You shouldn't have raw pointers in your callback, there should be no need to call delete anywhere, and you need critical sections and wait conditions before using an object whose ownership has passed to an asynchronous call.

Comment: callback is called when server responds to HTTP request. Server doesn't even know about user object and is implemented in PHP so it has nothing to do with deletion. I only need a way of knowing whether callback has deleted user or not.

Comment: In that case you can use smart pointers as Rob suggested or simply signal from the call back either by setting a flag which must always be checked before calling delete or sending a message to delete handler and always using that mechanism to delete. Smart pointers are cleaner.

Answer (score 3):

Once you've called `saveOnServer` of a zombie user, the request is the effective "owner" of that user object. Don't free it yourself since there's something else that still intends to use it and delete it later.

In fact, if the server action can return asynchronously, then the user object might get destroyed at any time. You should cease using it entirely from the other code. You've granted control of that object to the request, and you must stop using it from anywhere else:

```
user = new User();
user->zombie = true; // set *before* transferring ownership to server
user->saveOnServer();
user = NULL;
//some code comes here
user = new User();
```

If you don't want the request to use that object anymore, then you need to provide some facility for "canceling" the save-on-server action so that it doesn't use the object.

---

Another option is to use smart pointers. In your main code, store the object in a `shared_ptr`. In the request object, store it in a `weak_ptr`. That way, if your main code wants to destroy the user object, it can simply call `user.reset()`. Then if the callback attempts to use the `weak_ptr`, it will discover that the pointed-to object is no longer available. When using smart pointers, *neither* function should use `delete`. The pointer objects will manage the lifetime of the user for you.

```
shared_ptr<User> user = make_shared<User>()
user->saveOnServer();
//some code comes here
user.reset(new User());
```

In the `saveOnServer` function, use `shared_from_this` to create a `weak_ptr` to the object:

```
void User::saveOnServer(){
  Request *request = new Request();

  //send request on server and register the callback
  weak_ptr<User> self(shared_from_this());
  request ->setCallback(&userCallback, self);
}
```

In the callback, use that `weak_ptr`:

```
void userCallback(weak_ptr<User> data){
  shared_ptr<User) user = data.lock();
  if (!user)
    return;

  //do something here
}
```

Comment: Problem is that I need to reuse the user pointer for creating new users. I will definitely have a look at smart pointers. thanks

Comment: Then go ahead and reuse it. Nothing I've written here precludes that. You can reuse the *variable* as much as you want. But if you've transferred ownership of the *object*, then you mustn't continue using it. I illustrate that in my first code example by assigning `user = NULL` immediately after calling `user->saveOnServer()`. Notice that the variable gets re-assigned with `user = new User()` later, but nothing in between attempts to dereference `user` because that code doesn't have control over it anymore; it belongs to the request object instead.

Comment: Your solution works perfectly if user->zombie = true but if I do not want callback to delete it and set user->zombie = false then callback doesn't delete it and memory gets lost when I create a new user or set it to NULL. Is there anyway of checking if callback has deleted user if not then i check zombie. If false I delete it before creating a new user.

Comment: If the request is to own the user, then set `zombie = true` and `user = NULL`. If the request should not own the object, then set `zombie = false`. But you need to make that decision at the time you call `saveOnServer`. You can't wait till later because the callback might have already run, so it's too late to grant ownership elsewhere. The bottom line is that you need to be absolutely clear who owns the object. The owner (and only the owner) must destroy it.